# Partitioning a string in Python by a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, split, whitespace

I need to split a string into an array on word boundaries (whitespace) while maintaining the whitespace.

For example:

```
'this is  a\nsentence'
```

Would become

```
['this', ' ', 'is', '  ', 'a' '\n', 'sentence']
```

I know about [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) and [re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split), but neither of them quite do what I want and there is no `re.partition`.

How should I partition strings on whitespace in Python with reasonable efficiency?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = "this is  a\nsentence"
re.split(r'(\W+)', s) # Notice parentheses and a plus sign.
```

Result would be:

```
['this', ' ', 'is', '  ', 'a', '\n', 'sentence']
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have read the `re.split` docs more carefully.

Answer (score 4):

Symbol of whitespace in re is **'\s'** not **'\W'**

Compare:

```
import re


s = "With a sign # written @ the beginning , that's  a\nsentence,"\
    '\nno more an instruction!,\tyou know ?? "Cases" & and surprises:'\
    "that will 'lways unknown **before**, in 81% of time$"


a = re.split('(\W+)', s)
print a
print len(a)
print

b = re.split('(\s+)', s)
print b
print len(b)
```

produces

```
['With', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'sign', ' # ', 'written', ' @ ', 'the', ' ', 'beginning', ' , ', 'that', "'", 's', '  ', 'a', '\n', 'sentence', ',\n', 'no', ' ', 'more', ' ', 'an', ' ', 'instruction', '!,\t', 'you', ' ', 'know', ' ?? "', 'Cases', '" & ', 'and', ' ', 'surprises', ':', 'that', ' ', 'will', " '", 'lways', ' ', 'unknown', ' **', 'before', '**, ', 'in', ' ', '81', '% ', 'of', ' ', 'time', '$', '']
57

['With', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'sign', ' ', '#', ' ', 'written', ' ', '@', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'beginning', ' ', ',', ' ', "that's", '  ', 'a', '\n', 'sentence,', '\n', 'no', ' ', 'more', ' ', 'an', ' ', 'instruction!,', '\t', 'you', ' ', 'know', ' ', '??', ' ', '"Cases"', ' ', '&', ' ', 'and', ' ', 'surprises:that', ' ', 'will', ' ', "'lways", ' ', 'unknown', ' ', '**before**,', ' ', 'in', ' ', '81%', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'time$']
61
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
re.split('(\W+)','this is  a\nsentence')
```