# Avoid unescaping non-breaking space and '<', '>'

Tags: python, escaping

`html.unescape()` allows to unescape all the HTML entities and works perfectly, but I need to perform unescaping with a couple of exceptions: I'd like to have *nbsp* (non-breaking space), *lt* (<) and *gt* (>) left unchanged. Only these three entities.

For example, processing this text

```
The sensitivity of&nbsp;different micro-organisms to&nbsp;heat varies,
but if&nbsp;water is&nbsp;held at&nbsp;70&nbsp;&deg;C (158&nbsp;&deg;F)
for ten minutes, many organisms are killed &lt;...&gt;.
However, &laquo;Test&raquo; allows...
```

should result in

```
The sensitivity of&nbsp;different micro-organisms to heat varies,
but if water is&nbsp;held at&nbsp;70&nbsp;°C (158&nbsp;°F)
for ten minutes, many organisms are killed &lt;...&gt;.
However, «Test» allows...
```

Is there any elegant solution for achieving this? Can I make `html.unescape()` ignore particular entities?

Comment: Is replacing `<`, `>` and non-breaking spaces with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&nbsp;` *after* using `html.unescape()` an option?` `html.unescape()` is not configurable and a pretty complex beast, [see the current 3.7.0 implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/html/__init__.py#L28-L132).

Comment: Also, what about `&` ampersands? If your input has `&amp;lt;`, your output would become `&lt;` after unescaping. That's a big difference from `&lt;` in the input.

Comment: Input and output are supposed to be exactly the same as in the example above. There is no need to escape `&lt;` to `&amp;lt;` or replace `<`, `>` and non-breaking spaces with HTML entities after using `html.unescape()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `html.unescape()` is not configurable. I'd just re-escape using `html.escape()` plus a manual transformation of U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE codepoints:

```
import html

def reescape(s):
    return html.escape(html.unescape(s)).replace('\xa0', '&nbsp;')
```

Note that this *also* escapes `&` ampersands, because otherwise any input with `'&amp;lt;'` becomes `'&lt;'`, which is indistinguishable from input that used `'&lt;'` (where the `lt;` part can be any valid HTML entity minus the ampersand).

Demo:

```
>>> sample = '''\
... The sensitivity of&nbsp;different micro-organisms to&nbsp;heat varies,
... but if&nbsp;water is&nbsp;held at&nbsp;70&nbsp;&deg;C (158&nbsp;&deg;F)
... for ten minutes, many organisms are killed &lt;...&gt;.
... However, &laquo;Test&raquo; allows...
... '''
>>> print(reescape(sample))
The sensitivity of&nbsp;different micro-organisms to&nbsp;heat varies,
but if&nbsp;water is&nbsp;held at&nbsp;70&nbsp;°C (158&nbsp;°F)
for ten minutes, many organisms are killed &lt;...&gt;.
However, «Test» allows...
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`html.unescape` do not allow exceptions but you can make use of `re.split` to do what you want. This is my solution:

```
import html
import re

s = """The sensitivity of&nbsp;different micro-organisms to&nbsp;heat varies,
but if&nbsp;water is&nbsp;held at&nbsp;70&nbsp;&deg;C (158&nbsp;&deg;F)
for ten minutes, many organisms are killed &lt;...&gt;.
However, &laquo;Test&raquo; allows..."""

parts = re.split(r'(&nbsp;|&lt;|&gt;)', s)
for i, part in enumerate(parts):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        parts[i] = html.unescape(parts[i])
print("".join(parts))
```

The `re.split` with capture in the regex will not only split, but keep the delimiter in the output list. And we take every other element to `html.unescape` can avoid the particular tokens you want as exception. You can see [Partitioning a string in Python by a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932059/partitioning-a-string-in-python-by-a-regular-expression) for an example of how `re.split` would work.